# How to schedule orders?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a delivery model. I made a model that delivers products from a distributor to restaurants with a rate of 30 orders/day, and selects randomly the restaurant for each order. Now I want to schedule orders (for example : order1->restaurant1;order2->restaurant3...). I made an agent called restaurants (population of agents).

[this image shows that my orders are coming with a rate of 30 per day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGFDd.png)

[this image shows that new order is sent to the distributor but i can't specify the exact restaurant I guess it chooses it randomly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45H2k.png)

[restaurants agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf7x2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your restaurant is stored within the `Order` itself when you create the `Order` (this is the "`this`" in your `Order` creation code).

So your `distributeur` receives `Order`s and can process them directly by accessing the `Order`s parameter, likely called "Restaurant" or similar (you did not share what `Order` looks like.

I think you misunderstand what you model is actually doing. It is not the distributor creating orders, it is the restaurants themselves. And they "sign" orders with `this`, meaning they say "it was me creating this order", then sending it to the distributor.

Now your distributor can do with them what you like...